# Как заполнить цветом площадь между линиями в Android?

Tags: android

Есть код, который создаёт две кривые линии, которые протягиваются слева наверх. Как можно заполнить нужным цветом ту площадь, которая образовалась между ними c учетом того, что линии могут двигаться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class DrawView extends View {

Paint paint;
Path path1 = new Path();
Path path2 = new Path();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    path1.reset();
    path2.reset();

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    path1.moveTo(0, 750);
    path2.moveTo(0, 900);

    path1.cubicTo(185, 250, 599, 177, 585, 0);
    path2.cubicTo(350, 250, 750, 177, 900, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path1, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 750);
    path.cubicTo(185, 250, 599, 177, 585, 0);
    path.lineTo( 900,0 );
    path.cubicTo( 750, 177, 350, 250, 0, 900);
```

Нарисовал поверх ваших - все точно.

```
    canvas.drawPath(path1, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL );
    paint.setColor( Color.WHITE );
    paint.setAlpha( 128 );
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Я ещё не до конца разобрался в координатах. Можете подсказать как заполнить цветом всю площадь, которая находится над первой линии, которая начинается с x = 0, y = 0?

pa.moveTo(0,0);
pa.cubicTo(185, 250, 599, 177, 585, 0);
pa.lineTo(750, 0);

У меня здесь получается полуовал

Comment: Под первой можно moveTo( 0, 750); cubicTo(185, 250, 599, 177, 585, 0); line to(0,0) close

Comment: Спасибо, работает